# parbox in enumerate

Tags: parbox

The box is exceeds the right boundary probably because of the `textwidth`. I would like to have it aligned. Besides, what is `\noindent` for? Why it seems to be the same with or without it.

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item The Young King tells the story of the illegitimate shepherd son of the recently dead king's daughter of an unnamed country. 
\noindent
\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{%
The Young King tells the story of the illegitimate shepherd son of the recently dead king's daughter of an unnamed country. 
    }%
}
\end{enumerate}
```

[image: effect]

Comment: To complete the @Phelype Oleinik's answer, \noindent is used at the beginning of the paragraph, it suppresses the paragraph indentation. It has no effect when used in the middle of a paragraph.

Comment: @MajidAbdolshah if `noindent` is placed before `\begin{enumerate}`, I could see the difference?

Comment: No there is no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because `\textwidth` is the *whole* text width. And when you are in an enumerate environment, some of this width is occupied by the labels.

To get the correct spacing you should use the `\textwidth` minus the `\leftmargin` of the enumerate environment.

Also, the `\fbox` command has an `\fboxsep`, which is the space between the text and the box. The default for this is `3pt`. You should also take this into account when creating the `\parbox`.

So the final code should be like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item The Young King tells the story of the illegitimate shepherd son of the recently dead king's daughter of an unnamed country. 

\fbox{%
    \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-\leftmargin-\itemindent-2\fboxsep}{%
The Young King tells the story of the illegitimate shepherd son of the recently dead king's daughter of an unnamed country. 
    }%
}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

And the result is:

[image]

Though, notice that the text outside the box is now wider than the one inside. This is because of the `\fboxsep`. Now you have another option: set the `\fboxsep` to `0pt`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item The Young King tells the story of the illegitimate shepherd son of the recently dead king's daughter of an unnamed country. 

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\fbox{%
    \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-\leftmargin-\itemindent-2\fboxsep}{%
The Young King tells the story of the illegitimate shepherd son of the recently dead king's daughter of an unnamed country. 
    }%
}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

and the result will be:

[image]

It is up to you to decide which one you prefer.

Answer (score 5):

Not with `parbox` directly but with `tcolorbox`, which respects the current `\linewidth` automatically. See the various options for the box look.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{parboxlike}[1][]{%
  enhanced,sharp corners,colback=white,left=3pt,right=3pt,boxsep=0pt,nobeforeafter,before skip=5pt,#1}


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item The Young King tells the story of the illegitimate shepherd son of the recently dead king's daughter of an unnamed country. 
\begin{parboxlike}
  The Young King tells the story of the illegitimate shepherd son of the recently dead king's daughter of an unnamed country. 
\end{parboxlike}

\item The Young King tells the story of the illegitimate shepherd son of the recently dead king's daughter of an unnamed country. 
\begin{parboxlike}[colback=white!80!yellow,title={And now with a title and colourful background},coltitle=black,colbacktitle=cyan]
  The Young King tells the story of the illegitimate shepherd son of the recently dead king's daughter of an unnamed country. 
\end{parboxlike}

\end{enumerate} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `\textwidth`, you could use `\linewidth` and adjust it for the `\fbox` via `-2\fboxsep`.  This has the advantage that it will work at different list depths:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item The Young King tells the story of the illegitimate shepherd son of the recently dead king's daughter of an unnamed country. 

\fbox{%
    \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
The Young King tells the story of the illegitimate shepherd son of the recently dead king's daughter of an unnamed country. 
    }%
}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item The Young King tells the story of the illegitimate shepherd son of the recently dead king's daughter of an unnamed country. 
    
    \fbox{%
        \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
    The Young King tells the story of the illegitimate shepherd son of the recently dead king's daughter of an unnamed country. 
        }%
    }
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```